# How do I log russian text or non-latin?

Tags: ios, character-encoding, internationalization, xcode4.3, nslog

Everything works well in the previous version of XCode. But today in the XCode 4.3.2 I have a problem. How do I log russian text or non-latin?

```
NSLog(@"russian text: русский текст");

NSString *text = @"russian text: русский текст";
const char *textC = [text UTF8String];    
NSString *getText = [NSString stringWithCString:textC encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"___text: %@", getText);
```

My logs

```
russian text: —Ä—É—Å—Å–∫–∏–π —Ç–µ–∫—Å—Ç
___text: russian text: —Ä—É—Å—Å–∫–∏–π —Ç–µ–∫—Å—Ç
```

**UPDATE:**

The bug take place only on real device (ipod touch 5.1). It works properly on iphone simulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. You need to change debugger from LLDB to GDB in Product->Edit Sheme. LLDB doesn't work correctly with russian language.

Answer (score 2):

Works fine for me in Xcode 4.2, so it's either a 4.3.2 bug or your source file encoding is wrong.

Check the "Preferences / Text Editing / Editing tab / Default text encoding" setting and make sure it's set to Unicode (UTF-8).

If it is, open the file in BBEdit and double check its encoding. It's possible there's an old MacRoman or other encoding set on the file.

Comment: Default text encoding and file encoding is set to Unicode (UTF-8). I checked the file with BBEdit.

Comment: fwiw, it works fine for me debugging to an iPad 3 using Xcode 4.2.

Answer (score 2):

**Update:**

Works fine in Simulator for me.

However on a real device running iOS 5.1 I am getting the same wrong, disturbed output as you.
So it probably is an XCode 4.3.2 bug.

---

I tested your code on XCode 4.3.2 and it works fine for me.

My logs:

```
2012-04-15 15:44:28.545 test[25799:15203] russian text: русский текст
2012-04-15 15:44:28.548 test[25799:15203] ___text: russian text: русский текст
```

Comment: did you tested on real device?

Comment: only tested it on simulator first. just checked on a real device and got the same wrong output. I edited my answer to reflect this.