# Apple Push Notification in Hebrew shows as '????????'

Tags: iphone, ios, encoding, windows-server-2008, apple-push-notifications

I have an iPhone app that gets push notifications from a Windows server as well as other data over HTTP, the data I get over HTTP looks good on the screen, but the push notification shows only questions marks, I tried encoding it as UTF-8, ASCII but still I get the question marks, my iPhone is configured to hebrew and i have a he.lproj file and no en file

does any one has an idea??

Comment: I know for a fact that UTF8 encoded Hebrew works for APNS. The app configuration is irrelevant, show your server-side code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got what was the bug, Im using a push notification server based on [Moon-Apns](https://github.com/arashnorouzi/Moon-APNS) and after checking in source code i found out that they are encoding the needed chars to UTF-8... but they dont use the string they encode to, they pass the original string to the apn, so i fixed it and now all is well, thank you all for trying to help me! if anyone need this fix ill be glad to point to it and give the code

Comment: "I am trying for about 2 days for the same thing you did. I am using moonapns and got the result in hexa decimal values in push notification.  I just wanna know what you did to both side server and client .................I ma applying this code given below on string before sending in notification..............StringBuilder encodedString = new StringBuilder();
   foreach (char c in rawString)
   {
    if ((int)c < 32 || (int)c > 127)
     encodedString.Append("\\u" + String.Format("{0:x4}", Convert.ToUInt32(c)));
    else
     encodedString.Append(c);
   }".

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that your server side in encoding Hebrew incorrectly. Try to ensure that server response is correct. I had the same problem with Russian encoding, it was solved only when we set php response code to UTF-8 (not Latin1 as it was set by default).

Answer (score 0):

Use nslog to see what data is receiving in pushnotification and appdelegate didreceive remote notification method, and if there is no data, then you have problem at server side that may be in correct parameter assigning to notification object

Comment: I get the number of letters as i send but see it as question marks

Comment: how you assiging it at server side and what output comes in NSLOG

Comment: In NSLog i see the same question marks, and the server is ok when i send the message in english

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the encoding on both the sending and receiving site is the same (e.g. UTF8).

For me specific help, your code is necessary.

If you are not able to print non-latin text with NSLog(), [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10162355/how-do-i-log-russian-text-or-non-latin/10162587#10162587) could probably help you.

Comment: changed the debugger but still get questions marks in push notification